# $\sigma$-algebra versus 'regular' algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The only difference I can see between a $\sigma$-algebra and a 'regular' algebra is that when dealing with the unions of subsets, the $\sigma$-algebra defines the operation for an infinite amount of unions.

1. What does this mean in practise, is there an algebra of subsets that could not be classed as a $\sigma$-algebra?
2. And in reverse, is there some $\sigma$-algebra that could not be classed as an algebra of subsets?
3. Did someone 'invent' the concept of an algebra of subsets, and then someone else decided it wasn't sufficient so they invented the $\sigma$-algebra to deal with an infinite number of subsets?

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable operations of $\cap, \cup, - $ while set-algebras are generally finite.  Given the set $X=\{0,1\}$, there is an algebra, $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$, given by $\mathcal{A}=\{\{0\},\{1\},\emptyset,X\}$. More generally finite algebras always have $2^n$ elements.

Comment: In a book I am reading they say that $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathcal{A} = $ collection of sets $A \subset \mathbb Z$ such that $A$ is finite or $A^c$ is finite. Apparently this shows that it is an algebra, but NOT a $\sigma-$ algebra. But I don't see this, any explanation?

Comment: @TylerHilton Look at the sets $S_k=\{2n\in \mathbf{Z}: |n|\leq k\}$ for $k=1,2,3,...$. That is, $S_k=\{-2k,-2k+2,\dots,0,\dots,2k-2,2k\}$. Certainly each $S_k$ is finite, but $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}S_k=2\mathbf{Z}$, the set of even integers. Neither this set or it's complement, $2\mathbf{Z}+1$, the set of odd integers is finite. So, $\mathcal{A}$ is not closed under countable unions, hence not a $\sigma$-algebra.